# Add class to single based on the order poistion of posts in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a simple system where the number of posts are fixed but the order of the posts can dynamically be changed by the user. So "post X" can be the first in order but can later be last.

Inside the admin I already made it simple to change the order in the admin by drag and drop.

Is it possible to output a class based on the position order of the post? For instance: .order-position-1, .order-position-2 etc. I already know how to echo a class inside the body.

```
$extraBodyClasses = array();

if ( is_singular( 'post' ) )  { 

    array_push($extraBodyClasses, "theClassName");
}

echo body_class($extraBodyClasses);
```

How can i echo the "order postion" of the post inside a class?

Comment: Do you want to echo out the classname with a counter  like classname-1 and so on with each of the posts. So that when the user from dashboard can re-order posts can see which order post is this?

Comment: yes, that would work great!

Comment: so just concatenate the post id with the class!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it was **'ing simple.

```
get_post_field( 'menu_order', $post_id);
```